# How to automatically rescale webfonts when one resizes browser etc

Tags: responsive-design, font-awesome

I am using webfonts, in particular FontAwesome which is great.

```
<i class="fa fa-book" style="color:purple; font-size:100px; padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;"></i>
```

I am now trying to work out how I can get this font to automatically scale down when the browser is decreased in size? Also when this is viewed on an Ipad or other mobile device.

Many thanks in advance.

**Update**

I believe I have not made myself clear. I am trying to get the web fonts scale up and down when the browser size changes, or when the device changes ie IPad as opposed to desktop browser. In essence have the fonts react responsively. I may have missed something since I am very new to this.

Comment: What do you mean by automatically scale down? Does the font has to be relative to the viewport size? You have to be careful with this approach because you will need to set a minimum font size. Also, have you looked into CSS media queries? What have you tried?

Comment: Hi Terry, thanks for the reply. I have not tried anything in particular apart from going down the web font route. I believe what I am trying to achieve is having a standard size, then if the device is bigger say on a big desktop screen then the icons can grow, if on a smart phone, then shrink. I guess I need to adopt a recommended/standard approach to this. At present if I minimise my browser over my fixed sized font ie font-size:100px then I would just see part of my icon, if icon is bigger than browser space.

Comment: Use CSS media query breakpoints to determine what you want to do for each screen resolution/size - http://www.projectseven.com/products/templates/pagepacks/adaptations/tutorials/media-queries/. I would also recommend using em values instead of pixels, as you can easily set a base font size and all sizes will be relative to it.

Comment: Thanks for this Terry. Do I assume that this is only achievable with CSS3?

Comment: Also good tip on em values. Thanks

Comment: The answer may also be JQuery ie the flowtype plugin, see: http://simplefocus.com/flowtype/demo.html. Seems to be designed for WebFonts.

Comment: If you add an answer then I can mark it up. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking to change the font size based on the viewport size, I would recommend using CSS media query breakpoints. There is almost endless possibilities of how screen sizes or resolutions and orientations can be combined, but [this article](http://www.projectseven.com/products/templates/pagepacks/adaptations/tutorials/media-queries/) gives you the common breakpoints that are useful when designing for mobile, tablet and desktop optimized layouts.

Also, when it comes to font sizes, I strongly recommend using em units instead of pixels. In that way, you can set a base font size on the, say `<body>` element, and then set the font size in the rest of the page relative to that value. This is assuming that for majority of the browsers out there, 16px is the *de facto* font size:

```
html {
    font-size: 100%;
}
body {
    font-size: 1em; /* 16px default */
    /* If you want the baseline grid to be 10px, use font-size: 62.5% instead */
}
h1 {
    font-size: 5em; /* 80px, because 16*5=80 */
}
```

For the breakpoint, say, width of less than 680px:

```
/* Breakpoint for tablets */
@media only screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 679px) {
    body {
        font-size: .5em; /* Sets document font size to 8px */
    }
}
```

This will then cause font size across the page (that are using em units of course) to be reduced by 50%.